# Why does this C++ code compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Can someone explain to me why the following code compiles? Is it ignored by the compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    1234;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why it shouldn't compile?

Comment: It compiles, anyway I think it produces "Statement has no effect" warning.

Comment: As someone who wasn't ever extremely proficient in C++ to begin with, I'll admit that this confuses me - why isn't 1234; a syntax error? I mean, it's not a statement, right? Not a keyword, doesn't declare or instantiate a variable. I'm sure this is obvious to the rest of you but unfortunately not me. Looking forward to seeing the answer. (RE DeadMG: So it's because 1234; could be a macro?)

Comment: Because you're using a non-standard C++ compiler.

Comment: @Mark, `1234` cannot be a macro, but it *can* be the result from *expansion* of a macro that under other circumstances might expand to something a little more meaningful.

Comment: Turn on warnings. Set warnings to be treated like errors (as they usually are) then it will not compile. Its just that default compiler settings are lax.

Comment: @Noah, I've compiled it successfully with gcc and MSVC++.. What should I compile it with?

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: In C++ you're supposed to `#include <cXXXX>` instead of `<XXXX.h>`, and in this case `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @Rob Excellent.. My mind is at rest!

Comment: If you're bothered by this then I supposed I could give you a heart attack with this: `int main() { 5["abcdefg"]; }`

Comment: @MLimpkin In response to Noah's comments, please see my answer and my comment on his answer. Your compiler is behaving just fine.

Answer (score 8):

The Standard obliges implementers to allow statements even with no apparent effect. This is mainly because through the magic of macros and templates, they're surprisingly easy to come up with.

Comment: you probably mean *to allow* ? Most compilers don't keep them and discard such code, generating nothing for them. +1, for the macro magic.

Comment: Yes, but the standard doesn't oblige that this code compiles.

Comment: @hhafez: Actually, in line with C++'s philosophy, it's more that there's no reason to *disallow* such statements.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with this code. It's completely legal. It doesn't do anything, but it's completely legal. Your compiler -- with the right warning settings -- may warn you that it's utterly useless, but it's completely compliant.

Comment: 6.2.1 in C++2003: "Expression statements have the form `expression-statement: expressionopt ;` The expression is evaluated and its value is discarded." Please remove the downvote.

Comment: Yes, section-point-paragraph gets confused with subsections, though the community (at large) seems split over 6.2/1 and 6.2p1.

Comment: @Fred Seems like the community is split on just about everything. Hardly news :P

Answer (score 3):

A good compiler will give you a warning that you have a statement that has no side effect a (null statement effectively), however null statements are allowed in C/C++ so there will be no compile error.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the statement `1234;` as similar to the statement `getc();` in that both statements "return" (evaluate to) a value, but nothing is done with the return value.  The getc() call has the side effect of consuming a character from standard input, so you're more likely to see that in a program than a bare number.  But both are legal.

DeadMG has a good note on why it's a good idea to allow this.  It's not because `1234` might be defined as a macro (because as far as I know, that's not allowed).  It's because, especially with more complex macros, it's easy to end up with a macro that might reduce to some statement that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Correct. A macro definition may not begin with a number.

Answer (score 3):

In C (and thus C++), ***an expression is a statement*** and is evaluated for its side effects even if the result is discarded. If it doesn't have any side effects, the compiler might find out and optimized it away (very likely in your case), but it must still compile the code.

Of course, any compiler will warn about that if that warning isn't disabled explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on warnings.
Set warnings to be treated like errors (as they usually are).

Now it will behave as you would expect:

```
> cat t.cpp
int main() {
    1234;
    return 0;
}
> g++ t.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:2: warning: statement has no effect
```

Its just that default compiler settings are lax

Comment: `1234;` is still a valid C++ statement

Comment: @MartinYork What you expect and what's actually true may -- and in this case, appear to be -- two very different things. The compiler warning is only a warning because in fact the code is valid.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Obviously its a warning. But because I added the -Werror flag no code was produced. So it acted like it was an error. Because must warning generated by the compiler should be treated like errors.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you captain obvious.

Comment: @MartinYork: Yes, we know that. I don't see how that makes this an answer to the question. Not only is the production of a warning here unmandated by the standard (and therefore not guaranteed for any arbitrary toolchain), but his question was not "how do I make this not compile?".

Comment: @Martin What I meant was pretty much what Tomalak just said... ie. the question is : why is it ok to do this in C++ ?

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal: True. I was answering the unasked question. How do I make it behave like I want.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1234 is a constant, it lets you get away with it.  Replacing it with 'x' (without declaring variable x) or 'This doesn't compile' should cause it to fail.

Essentially it is an empty statement, so no harm no foul and it discards the code and keeps going.